# IE6 invisible text in 7 lines HTML, is there a fix?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

It took me forever to reduce the problem to this.  I cannot express the amount of frustration I'm experiencing, and if I did, it would not be suitable for any website.  Ever.  Here is the HTML code that is causing me epic pain:

```
<div style="padding: 5px; background: #EEE">
    This text is invisible. Remove either padding or background to see this.  
    <div>
        <div style="float: left;">left</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The text is invisible, unless you highlite it or drag a window over top of it, or something crazy like that.

This problem is resolved if you remove padding or remove the background.

How can I fix this?

Comment: +1 just cos I remember the pain, hope your day gets better :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ve been bitten by [Peek-a-boo](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html).

From that link, your options are:

1. Keep the clearing div from touching the float, or avoid using a background on div#floatholder. Not exactly ideal.
2. Give both div#floatholder and div#float 'position: relative'. Be sure to fully test this method.
3. Give div#floatholder hasLayout (now the preferred method)

Comment: Thank you so much, you probably saved my keyboard from getting smashed.  width:100% worked on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like classic hasLayout problem. Add a width to your outer-most div or try any of the other methods described [here](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

Comment: @Sam you can up vote all helpful answers, not just the one that you accept.

Comment: I would if I could... I don't feel like going through the whole openID bull to create an account